# python 2.7 read multiple line from text file

Tags: python, loops, readline

I have started to learn python, and have the question below. Please advise.

```
CZ:xxx
CZ:yyy
CZ:zzz
PD:EOL
CZ:uuu
CZ:vvv
CZ:www 
PD:EOL
```

how to read the line show individually

```
CZ:xxx
CZ:yyy
CZ:zzz
PD:EOL
```

I tried the below coding.

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f
    for line in f:
        if 'CZ' in line:
            print line
            break
```

but only show the first line.... help

Comment: just remove the break and will be done

Answer (score 3):

You have added `break` , which is not required.

```
with open('test.txt','r') as f
    for line in f:
        if 'CZ' in line:
            print line
```

Ouput:

```
CZ:xxx
CZ:yyy
CZ:zzz
```

If you want to display first 4 lines use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f
    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        if index < 4 and 'CZ' in line:
            print line
            continue
        break
```

Comment: i remove the break result will show                                             CZ:xxx
CZ:yyy
CZ:zzz
CZ:uuu
CZ:vvv
CZ:www                                                                                                             i would like show the first 4 line only

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `str.startswith`

**Ex:**

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("CZ"):
            print line
```

Comment: According to OPs sample data it is in the start